# wrong static path while adding new key value pair to an existing object

Tags: redis, lua, redisjson

I'm trying to add new key value pair to an existing object but with no success.
the object looks like:

```
"weight": {
            "options": {
              
            },
            "value": 50
}
```

my code is as following:

```
local optionId = 'a161713a-1987-4974-acfc-dd0a56ad99e7';
local weight = 20;
redis.call('JSON.SET', schemaKey, weightPath .. '.'..optionId, weight,'NX');
```

and i got error
`wrong static path`

Comment: What is "weightPath"? Please notice a jsonpath should start with a `$` sign. Which path did you try to generate?

Comment: @GuyKorland ```weightPath``` value is ```$.weight.options```

Comment: Which version of RedisJSON are you using?

Answer (score 0):

While this might be late, I suspect there is a recursive descent in your path, that is some double dots like in `$..weight.options.aa` and that is currently not supported by redis SET.
The subject is discussed [here](https://github.com/RedisJSON/RedisJSON/issues/788).